# Mobile SDK Hybrid Remote App - Login with Google is broken

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on

My mobile SDK page launches a community login page on startup; the login page includes a "login with google" link that kicks off auth through a configured Google Auth Provider in the org (e.g.,  `/services/auth/sso/<OrgId>/Google?community={!URLENCODE($Site.baseSecureUrl)}&startURL={!startUrl}`).

[Google has disallowed OAUTH via WebView](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html) for details.  They recommend using Google Sign-in, and there's even a [Cordova Plugin for that](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus), but how do I integrate that with the Salesforce login process?﻿  The Google Sign-in API returns a ServerAuthCode, which sounds like Oauth's "Web Server Flow", but all the docs seem to indicate that's support for other apps using SF for SSO, but how do I initiate SSO to Salesforce with the token?